# Lazyload and Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2, jquery-lazyload

I'm trying to run Fancybox and Lazyload together but Lazyload needs "data-src" on the img tag instead of "src". Fancybox doesn't work anymore when I change "src" to "data-src". Can someone help me ?